# Не удаляется файл java после распаковки

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных, zip

Уже задавал вопрос на эту тему, но, видимо, дал недостаточно информации/некорректно задал.
У меня есть функция, в которую подаются 2 параметра: путь к архиву и директория его распаковки. После распаковки архива сам архив должен удаляться, но, не смотря на то, что он должен, он не удаляется.
Пробовал "ловить" ошибку. Ошибка гласит о том, что файл занят другим процессом, но  я не понимаю каким, может я слепой, может недостаточно опыта. Буду рад, если поможете.
**Функция:**

```
public static void unzip(String source, String out) throws IOException {

        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(source))) {
            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            while (entry != null) {
                File file = new File(out, entry.getName());
                System.out.println("Разархивируем: " + entry.getName());
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                } else {
                    File parent = file.getParentFile();
                    if (!parent.exists()) {
                        parent.mkdirs();
                    }
                    try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
                        int bufferSize = Math.toIntExact(entry.getSize());
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize > 0 ? bufferSize : 1];
                        int location;
                        while ((location = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            bos.write(buffer, 0, location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();

        }
        File file = new File (source);
        if (file.delete()) { //ТУТ ФАЙЛ ДОЛЖЕН УДАЛИТЬСЯ
            System.out.println (file.getName ()+" deleted");
        } else {
            System.out.println (file.getName ()+" not deleted");
        }
    }
```

**Вызов функции:**

```
public static void getUpdate(String login, int ozu)  {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.test/files/client_mc/client1165.zip");
                HttpURLConnection updcon;
                updcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println(updcon);
                File client = new File(util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator ,"client1165.zip");
                long cll_web = updcon.getContentLength();
                System.out.println(cll_web);
                FileOutputStream fw = null;

                if ((client.length() != cll_web) && cll_web > 1){
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(updcon.getInputStream());

                    fw = new FileOutputStream(client);

                    byte[] by = new byte[1024];
                    int count = 0;

                    while ((count = bis.read(by)) != -1){
                        fw.write(by, 0, count);
                        System.out.println("Скачано " + ((int) client.length() / 1048576) + "Мбайт из " + (cll_web / 1048576) + "Мб");
                    }
                    unzip(util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "client1165.zip", util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator); // ВЫЗОВ ФУНКЦИИ 
                }
                start_m(login, ozu);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
                .start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил. Проблема была в моей невнимательности.

Я не закрыл `fw(FileOutputStream)` в главном потоке. Перед вызовом функции `unzip()` написал `fw.close()`, и всё заработало.

```
public static void getUpdate(String login, int ozu)  {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.test/files/client_mc/client1165.zip");
                HttpURLConnection updcon;
                updcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                System.out.println(updcon);
                File client = new File(util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator ,"client1165.zip");
                long cll_web = updcon.getContentLength();
                System.out.println(cll_web);
                FileOutputStream fw = null;

                if ((client.length() != cll_web) && cll_web > 1){
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(updcon.getInputStream());

                    fw = new FileOutputStream(client);

                    byte[] by = new byte[1024];
                    int count = 0;

                    while ((count = bis.read(by)) != -1){
                        fw.write(by, 0, count);
                        System.out.println("Скачано " + ((int) client.length() / 1048576) + "Мбайт из " + (cll_web / 1048576) + "Мб");
                    }
                    fw.close(); // ЗАКРЫЛ СТРИМ
                    unzip(util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "client1165.zip", util.getWorkDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator);
                }
                start_m();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
                .start();
    }
```